# Define CSS property value based on PHP variable

Tags: php, html, css

I want to define the font-weight for my `tr` element based on a PHP variable. What am I doing wrong in this code?

```
<?
    $vartest = 1;
?>

<table>
  <tr style="font-weight: <? ($vartest === 1) ? echo bold : echo normal ?>">
    <td>aaaaaaa</td>
    <td>bbbbbbb</td>                                        
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: *Ternary **operators*** are no replacement for `if..else`. You cannot issue commands after `?` and `:`, only expressions that return a value. So it has to be `echo ($vartest === 1) ? 'bold' : 'normal'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary expression is wrong. Try with -

```
<tr style="font-weight: <? echo ($vartest === 1) ? 'bold' : 'normal'; ?>">
```

Comment: Ok I was doing wrong your solution worked for me now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
<?php

    $vartest = 1;
?>

<table>
  <tr style="font-weight: <?php echo ($vartest === 1) ? 'bold' : 'normal' ?>">
    <td>aaaaaaa</td>
    <td>bbbbbbb</td>                                        
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What output you are getting and what is your expected output?

Comment: I'm getting my row not in bold but it should be in bold because $vartest is equal 1.

Comment: Check the HTML source, it is possible that PHP is echoing properly but you are not able to see the boldness due to some other reason

Comment: `<?php echo` can be replaced with `<?=` =)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
<table>
<?php 
$result=($vartest === 1)?"<tr style='font-weight:bold'>":"<tr style='font-weight:normal'>";
    echo $result; ?>
        <td>aaaaaaa</td>
        <td>bbbbbbb</td>                                        
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Let me know if it is helpful

Comment: It didn't work, but I'm looking for a solution with ternary expression.

Comment: I have edited my answer as you wanted. Check now and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Add `""` for String in your syntax.

```
<tr style="font-weight: <? echo ($vartest === 1) ?  "bold" :  "normal" ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like this, using css to make it pre-defined:

```
<?php
$Class = "bold";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        tr.bold{
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        tr.normal{
            font-weight: normal;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr class="<?php echo $Class; ?>">
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>def</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```